# Devise_token_auth and Devise login with username and email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I continuously get errors when trying to add token authentication to my existing rails application and it's stemming from the devise authentication_keys. In my rails 4 app I allow users to login with either a username or email and I'd like to provide the same functionality for the API.

The error I'm getting when logging in from the API is as follows

```
Started POST "/api/v1/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-19 23:40:26 -0400
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"login"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"login"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (login = 'email@example.com' AND provider='email')  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: login: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (login = 'email@example.com' AND provider='email')  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

SQLite3::SQLException - no such column: login:
```

The code for the user model is below. The problem is stemming from the User load as it is not converting the login parameter to search via the email (or username). But the code below works totally fine for regular devise logins.

```
#User.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions.to_h).where(['lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value', { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions.to_h).first
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help or guidance!

**EDIT**
When sending the params as email and password there is also an error.

```
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"email"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Unpermitted parameters: email, format, session
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 49ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. From the [Devise doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), you need to do the following:

   - `app/models/user.rb`

     ```
     attr_accessor :login
     ```
   - `config/initializers/devise.rb`

     ```
     Devise.setup do |config|
        config.authentication_keys = [:login]
        config.case_insensitive_keys = [:login]
     end
     ```
2. `devise_token_auth` is unmaintained ([cf unmerged PR](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/pull/395/files)) and therefore out-of-sync with Devise, which is why you need to override SessionsController:

   - `config/routes.rb`

     ```
     Rails.application.routes.draw do
       namespace :api do
         scope module: :v4  do
           mount_devise_token_auth_for "User", at: "auth", controllers: {
             sessions: "api/v4/devise_token_auth/sessions"
           }
         end
       end
     end
     ```
   - `app/controllers/api/v4/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb`

     ```
     module Api
       module V4
         module DeviseTokenAuth
           class SessionsController < ::DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController
             def create
               # Check
               field = (resource_params.keys.map(&:to_sym) & resource_class.authentication_keys).first

               @resource = nil
               if field
                 q_value = resource_params[field]

                 if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(field)
                   q_value.downcase!
                 end

                 q = "#{field.to_s} = ? AND provider='email'"

                 if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name.downcase.starts_with? "mysql"
                   q = "BINARY " + q
                 end

                 # LOG IN BY EMAIL AND USERNAME
                 if field == :login
                   @resource = resource_class.where("email = ? OR username = ?", q_value, q_value).first
                 else
                   @resource = resource_class.where(q, q_value).first
                 end
                 # LOG IN BY EMAIL AND USERNAME END
               end

               if @resource && valid_params?(field, q_value) && (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) || @resource.active_for_authentication?)
                 valid_password = @resource.valid_password?(resource_params[:password])
                 if (@resource.respond_to?(:valid_for_authentication?) && !@resource.valid_for_authentication? { valid_password }) || !valid_password
                   render_create_error_bad_credentials
                   return
                 end
                 # create client id
                 @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
                 @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

                 @resource.tokens[@client_id] = {
                   token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token),
                   expiry: (Time.now + ::DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
                 }
                 @resource.save

                 sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)

                 yield @resource if block_given?

                 render_create_success
               elsif @resource && !(!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) || @resource.active_for_authentication?)
                 render_create_error_not_confirmed
               else
                 render_create_error_bad_credentials
               end
             end
           end
         end
       end
     end
     ```
3. Test example

   ```
   resource "User sign in" do

     let(:user) { build(:user) }

     before(:each) do
       user.create_new_auth_token
     end

     post "/api/auth/sign_in" do
       parameter :email, "Email address"
       parameter :password, "Password for user"

       it "fails with incorrect login and password" do
         do_request(login: "user.does.not@exist.com", password: "wrong_password")
         expect(status).to eq(401)
         expect(JSON.parse(response_body)["errors"])
           .to include("Invalid login credentials. Please try again.")
       end

       it "logs in with correct username and password" do
         user.save!
         do_request(login: user.username, password: user.password)
         expect(status).to eq(200)
         expect(JSON.parse(response_body)["data"]["email"]).to include(user.email)
       end

       it "logs in with correct email and password" do
         user.save!
         do_request(login: user.email, password: user.password)
         expect(status).to eq(200)
         expect(JSON.parse(response_body)["data"]["email"]).to include(user.email)
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**Explanation:**

The method `find_for_database_authentication` used for the authentication can be found in [Devise's `database_authenticable.rb`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/69bee06ceee6280b54304928bb6e55c5064abad8/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb) file, which hosts the `DatabaseAuthenticatable` module.

This is responsible for authenticating your resource while using Devise.

This method is what you are overwriting in your `User` model, and this is why your authentication action is working fine when you use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

On the other hand, when you try to authenticate a resource with [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth), You are hitting the `create` action of the [`SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb).

This can be seen from your error trace:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-19 23:40:26 -0400
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
```

What this action does, as can be seen from [the file here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb), is that it looks at the params you are sending, and builds `key=>value` pairs from those, and then query the database with the keys.

So, in essence, when you send a param as:

```
{"login"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Your controller will basically go into the database and look for a row with `login` equal `email@example.com`, etc..

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, you have no column `login` in your database, what you have is `email`, ( remember that was why you were over-riding the devise's `find_for_database_authentication` method in your user model =>

```
where(conditions.to_h).where(['lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value', { :value => login.downcase }]).first
```

).

That is why you see the error you have in your error trace:

```
SQLite3::SQLException - no such column: login:
```

**Solution:**

So, one very simple thing you can do is that when you are sending a param for authentication by the [auth_token](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth), send it as `email` and `password`

```
{"email"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

and not as `login` and `password`

Hope this is clear.

> PS: You also will not want session validation when using token, as mentioned by Shadow above, so you might want to add the following to your base controller: `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }` But this does not have to do with your reported issue.

**Edit:**

This is the permited params method:

```
def resource_params
  params.permit(*params_for_resource(:sign_in))
end
```

So, you will have to send params inside a `"sign_in"` key as follow:

```
{"sign_in" => {"email"=>"email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Comment: I edited the question to show the results for sending the parameters as email and password. I believe this error is coming from the devise `:authentication_keys => [:login]` in the User model. I even tried adding email to authentication keys but that messed up the normal sign in (via HTML form). Any ideas of a work around to keep the HTML login working?

Comment: can you show your controller? the one you are using for creating a session? you have a `Unpermitted parameters: email` error. you will have to add `email` to permited params.

Comment: It's the devise_token_auth sessions controller which looks like it inherits from devise resource see [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb)

Comment: Yeah, smooth. Look at the last private method in that file: `resource_params`, the content of which I've added as edit to the answer. It require params inside a `sign_in` key. so, you should send params as: {sign_in: {email: "klsj@lsd.ls", password: "lskjdf"}}

Comment: the server responded with `Unpermitted parameters: sign_in, format, session` when changing to that request

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have almost the exact same problem. Adding `email` to the `authentication_keys` solved the token based authentication, but the html 'login' based `sign_in` doesnt work. If we add both `login` and `email` to authentication_keys, it expects both to be present  when signing in from html. So, how do we set up `authentication_keys` to support both the (virtual) login attribute for html, and the email for token based auth?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @sundayAdefila but I couldn't get your solution to work